# Is there a way to have InDesign respect the artboard set in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, artboard

When placing a `*.ai` in InDesign, InDesign auto-crops the frame if part of the Illustrator artboard is empty. Even if I outline the Illustrator artboard with a no-stroke, no-fill rectangle, InDesign will lop off the part where it sees no ink.

Is there a way to have InDesign respect the Illustrator artboard size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When placing an `ai` file

1. Check the checkbox <kbd>Show options</kbd> and
2. Then in the new modal window, select <kbd>Crop to: Crop</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Once you set this once using *Place* <kbd>⌘+D</kbd>, it will continue as the default for other placements, including via drag-and-drop.