# Illustrator artboard to InDesign with pages alignment

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, alignment, artboard

I want to export my artboard in Adobe Illustrator to Adobe InDesign as well as pages alignment. Anyone knows how to do it? I have searched on Adobe's website but I found nothing.

Comment: Hi ThunderFox, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you give us a bit more info? What do you mean with 'pages alingment'? A screenshot might help, visual people we are here. Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: possible duplicate, or at least useful information: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/indesign-ignores-illustrator-artboard

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to create InDesign pages from Illustrator.

Draw an image frame in InDesign and link to the illustrator file.

Comment: How to do that? Could you guide me?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/graphics-links.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this article and it's not my target.
I mean 1 artboard to 1 page in InDesign.How can i do this?
Help me pls,Thx for your guide.